# How to get and parse this JSON object to Android textview

Tags: java, android, json

I am using an API provided by **CryptoCompare**. I need to get **Symbol** and **Price** from this JSON object.

```
{
  "Response": "Success",
  "Message": "Do not take life too seriously. You will never get out of it alive.",
  "Data": [
    {
      "Symbol": "USD",
      "Price": 5660.94,
      "Open24Hour": 5155.13,
      "LastUpdateTS": 1507885905,
      "Volume24Hours": 222438.875,
      "Volume24HoursTo": 1214073220
    },
    {
      "Symbol": "EUR",
      "Price": 4757.16,
      "Open24Hour": 4318.19,
      "LastUpdateTS": 1507885905,
      "Volume24Hours": 26488.4023,
      "Volume24HoursTo": 120264888
    }
  ],
  "Type": 100
}
```

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: My friend, I suggest you at least try something. This is a task you can easily achieve googling a bit. Let me give you a hint: [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest you to store your data to **`List`**

So, Initialize two **`List`**

```
List<String> symbol = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> price = new ArrayList<String>();
```

then here you can store data

```
try {

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("Data");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        symbol.add(object.getString("Symbol"));
        price.add(object.getString("Price"));

    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This may be help you

Comment: please answer this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46730373/how-can-i-get-strings-from-a-complex-json-object-without-a-json-array

Answer (score 1):

How to do it ?

- If you meet `{}` in your code , you can use `JSONObject` to parse it .
- If you meet `[]` in your code , you can use `JSONArray` to parse it .
- And if you meet `[]` in your code , you can use `for loop` to get value in it .
- And you should use `try catch` in your code .

Try this .

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        String Response = jsonObject.optString("Response");
        JSONArray Data = jsonObject.optJSONArray("Data");
        for (int i = 0; i < Data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jo = Data.optJSONObject(i);
            String Symbol = jo.optString("Symbol");
            String Price = jo.optString("Price");
            String Open24Hour = jo.optString("Open24Hour");
            String LastUpdateTS = jo.optString("LastUpdateTS");
            String Volume24Hours = jo.optString("Volume24Hours");
            String Volume24HoursTo = jo.optString("Volume24HoursTo");
        }
} catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
try {

            JSONObject objresponse=new JSONObject("{\"Response\":\"Success\",\"Message\":\"Do not take life too seriously. You will never get out of it alive.\",\"Data\":[{\"Symbol\":\"USD\",\"Price\":5660.94,\"Open24Hour\":5155.13,\"LastUpdateTS\":1507885905,\"Volume24Hours\":222438.875,\"Volume24HoursTo\":1.21407322E+09},{\"Symbol\":\"EUR\",\"Price\":4757.16,\"Open24Hour\":4318.19,\"LastUpdateTS\":1507885905,\"Volume24Hours\":26488.4023,\"Volume24HoursTo\":120264888.0}],\"Type\":100}");
            JSONArray arrayData=objresponse.getJSONArray("Data");
            for (int i=0;i<arrayData.length();i++){
                JSONObject obj=arrayData.getJSONObject(i);
                String symbol=obj.getString("Symbol");
                float price=(float)obj.getLong("Price");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```